# Resizing an image using CV_INTER_AREA

Tags: c++, opencv

I have some strange behavior when resizing an image using CV_INTER_AREA. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong but I cannot figure it out. So, can someone tell me what's wrong with the following code:

```
Mat src = imread( File_Name );
Mat dst;
Size s( src.size().width / 10, src.size().height / 10 );
resize( src, dst, s, 0, 0, CV_INTER_AREA );
```

When saving dst it only results in an gray image ( uninitialized memory ) on Windows.

This works as expected:

```
Mat src = imread( File_Name );
Mat dst;
Size s( src.size().width / 10, src.size().height / 10 );
resize( src, dst, s );
```

Since I'm reducing the size I like to use CV_INTER_AREA and define the resulting of the destination image size using the dsize parameter.

Any help is welcome.

Thanks,
Christian

Comment: Which version of opencv ? did you compile with SSE instructions support ? (I once had problem with some flags of cv::resize() that were windows and SSE specific...?)

Comment: I'm working in debug mode right now and I have recompiled without SSE support. Still same problem. I'm working against the current git repository, version 2.4.9.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you may try cv::INTER_AREA instead of using CV_INTER_AREA in version 2.4.9.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the trunk ( 2.4.9 ) isn't working. When I try the 2.4 branch the code works.